# Required field validation rule for [Billing|Shipping]StateCode with State & Country picklists enabled?

Tags: validation, country-and-state

When using State & Country picklist functionality, is it possible to write a Validation Rule that targets the Billing State or Shipping State fields to make them required but only when the Country has States?

Since some Countries do not have States/Regions and this is a restricted picklist field, Salesforce prevents bad data at the database level as well as in the native UI. A Country with no States will always have a blank value in the State field(s).

So, for a Country which doesn't have any States configured, and therefore will accept no data in the Billing State or Shipping State address fields, what is the appropriate way to write the Validation Rule?

My functional requirement:

- If the Country has States and BillingStateCode is blank, display
  error.
- If the Country does not have States, BillingStateCode can (and
  must) be blank.

Comment: You may wish to vote on this IdeaExchange post: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqlNAAS. Related because if you could make individual address columns required, state and country picklist should work the way you're asking for here.

Comment: @CarolynGrabill, voted. Considering that idea has been out there for 7 years and it's still not been implemented, I'm not going to hold my breath. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you could implement the following validation rule on State:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(State, ''),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Country, 'CountryWithStates1'),
        ISPICKVAL(Country, 'CountryWithStates2'),
        ISPICKVAL(Country, 'CountryWithStates3')
    )
)
```

You'll have to manage the `OR` list yourself, but that seems tolerable.

If you would like to try a more programmatic approach, check out [this blog post](http://titancronus.com/blog/2014/05/01/salesforce-acquiring-dependent-picklists-in-apex/). It would allow you to write a trigger based validation something like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> countryToStates = GetDependentOptions('Lead', 'Country', 'State');
for (Lead newLead : newLeads)
{
    if (countryToStates.containsKey(newLead.Country) &&
        !countryToStates.get(newLead.Country).isEmpty() &&
        newLead.State == null)
    {
        newLead.State.addError(Label.State_Required);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I suspected too and it's a good answer. I'm hoping there is some hidden magic out there that will make it self-managed. As it stands, with this approach the admin needs to maintain the two lists - which is a little error prone.

Comment: Did you see my updated response? There is a way to do it programatically, though you will need to validate in a trigger instead of a validation rule.